# What do Pentagons Mean?

Tags: pokemon-series

Never gotten a solid answer on this. What do the Pentagons mean on a Pokémon's info card? Does it have anything to do with Kalos, and it's pentagon shape?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Pentagon means that the Pokémon was caught in this specific generation. Any Pokémon you imported via Bank or traded with a friend from another gen does not have the pentagon.